# How to add animation on tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to add animation when `UITableView` load cells (From top to Bottom) But getting no idea about this, please someone help me.

Below added a simple table view delegate methode with an array(arrHeader).

Thanks in advance

```
let arrHeader = ["City1", "City2", "City3"]


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrHeader.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = arrSubHeader[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add animation to each cell when it displayed? or an animation for the whole tableView?

Comment: I want to add to whole table

Comment: To make sure that I'm understanding what are you trying to achieve, the animation will be applicable on the tableview it self, not on each cell, right?

Comment: Yes! i just want that when my page load instead of coming all cell it comes one by one with animation(Top to Bottom).

Comment: Sorry but what you want is load the last cell first and the first cell last in order?

Answer (score 0):

Put your animation code in this `UItableView` delegate method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //TODO: animation code

}
```

this delegate method is called every time a new or old cell is going to be displayed on the iPhone/iPad screen.

So if you try something in this block with the cells it will reflect on them.

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
       didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }
```

this method gets called after a cell is being displayed.

Here is the github link for the Example:

Visit:  https://github.com/subhajitregor/TableCellCardDropAnimationExample

Comment: I have tried it but it only animate the first cell.

Comment: I do have a code in objective C, if you want I can share it with you.

Comment: Sure you can share.

Comment: Ok give me some time, let me put it in a demo project and I will share the link of github in the answer.

Comment: Please see the answer for the github link, if you need anything more feel free to ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128982/discussion-between-subhajit-halder-and-s-bharti).